# Eclipse - Unhandled exception type, компилятор предупреждает Parent exception вместо перечисления

Tags: java, eclipse

Использую Eclipse Oxygen, где Preferences - Java - Compiler - level 1.8. 
При компиляции кода

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        if(...) {
            throw new IOException();
        }else {
            throw new SQLException();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw e;
    }
}
```

выбрасывает предупреждение `Unhandled exception type SQLException` и по фиксу Add throws declaration добавляет `throws Exception`, как с уровнем компилятора ниже 1.7. Имея уровень 1.8, ожидаю фикс с перечислением в виде `throws IOException, SQLException`, как делает IntelliJ IDEA. Подскажите, как можно заставить Eclipse фиксить сигнатуру метода с перечислением throws, а не по throws одного Parent'а?